# Keep app running even if monogo dbconnection fails

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a simple app built with express and mongodb.

**Mongodb connection:**

```
var connect = function() {
var options = {
    server: {
        socketOptions: {
            keepAlive: 1,
            connectTimeoutMS: 30000
        }
    },
    replset: {
        socketOptions: {
            keepAlive: 1,
            connectTimeoutMS: 30000
        }
    }
};
mongoose.connect(url, options);
};

connect();
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', connect);
```

**I am starting my express app as:**

```
app.listen(1000);
```

It works with the happy path. The problem is if mongo connection fails, my app doesn't start.

```
events.js: 85
throw er; //Unhandled 'error' event
Error: failed to connect to []
```

I want to start app irrespective of db connection.
Also for some reason db throws an error my app gets kicked out. How do I keep my express app running and silently re-establish db connection if needed?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want handle the error case.

```
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
```

Picked directly from [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html)

Comment: This helps if db connection goes down after app is started. When I run my app and db connection is not valid, it fails on mongoose.connect.

Comment: @WhatisSober What is meant by `valid`? Can you give one example of `invalid` scenario so that i can think in that direction.